# How to run composer package in custom php project

Tags: php, composer-php

I have downloaded php phantom js using composer but I am not able to run this package in my php project. Is there any other requirements or engine needed to run composer package on custom php project. I have this folder structure

[image]

I am getting this error

> Fatal error: Class 'JonnyW\PhantomJs\Client' not found in D:\wamp\www\freelancer\practice\phantomget.php on line 5

because it is not getting the class

I have also change the class inclusion
use JonnyW\PhantomJs\Client;
to include_one('Client class path in vendor folder')
to directly get the class but it is showing other class errors

So is there any workaround to use this package on custom php project, I have this package here
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Till now I have not received any response regarding this question but finally I have found a solution by myself and this is my achievement. So hope this will help others in future.

So we only need to include one file and it will do all the stuff
so you need to include this in your php file where you want to use the package and it will run the package files. Wherever you want to use the package class you can include this code in your file and enjoy.

`require __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';`

Thanks to me.

Comment: You should try to save your own time and read some docs about Composer: https://getcomposer.org/doc/01-basic-usage.md#autoloading - these are basics.

Comment: This is basic for you after reading my answer but before that you were not in a picture to tell me this basic thing about composer.Thanks for link.